# Can only boot Kubuntu 20.04 in recovery mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, kubuntu, recovery-mode

I'm a Linux begginer. Yesterday I installed Kubuntu in a dual boot with Windows 10. It ran perfectly, I even configured and customized it. But this morning it came to my surprise that if I ran Kubuntu normally I get a black screen and have to kill the power of my laptop.

I have tried and noticed that I have to go to Ubuntu advanced options and run Kubuntu in recovery mode. It doesn't really matter but I want to run it normally. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Does pressing ESC or CTRL + F1 (or F2,F3)  or typing exit produce any results?

Comment: this doesn't happen every time, sometimes I try to boot the normal way and the screen gets black. As this doesn't happen always I don't know why it is. But none of what you say works, I just have to kill the power and restart